# AEM 6.1 Add Tab to Touch UI Page Properties

Tags: adobe, aem

I am trying to get adding new tabs and removing tabs/items in Page Properties working.

So far I have read through this similar question: http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__m3tp-there_is_anarticle.html

Which lead me to these Adobe links and the github example:

- https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/author/page-authoring/managing-pages.html#Creating%20a%20New%20Page%20-%20Touch-optimized%20UI
- https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/extending/customizing-page-properties/page-properties-views.html
- https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-authoring-extension-page-dialog/blob/master/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/demos/components/page/_cq_dialog/.content.xml

I have copied the github example of a **.context.xml** for the page's Page Properties and it is not hiding anything.

I also replaced **cq:showOnCreate="{Boolean}false"** with **cq:hideOnEdit="{Boolean}true"** like the previous adobe help forum suggested and this does not work either.

How do I hide and show items?

Also, in the past with Classic UI we were able to do something like this to include more tabs:

```
<sample
jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
path="/apps/company/components/Pages/basePage/sample_tab.infinity.json"
xtype="cqinclude"/>
```

How do I add new tabs in Touch UI with something similar to infinity.json? Granite include?

Answer (score 2):

You can reuse tabs in Touch just as you can in Classic by using `granite/ui/components/foundation/include` with the `path` property.

In the following example we have a Heading component that includes a normal text widget and pulls in a reusable Component Settings tab. I've placed the shared tabs under `/apps/mysite/dialogs/granite/tabs` but that's not a requirement, you can simply update the `path` property.

This is the component dialog at `/apps/mysite/components/heading/_cq_dialog.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    jcr:title="Heading"
    sling:resourceType="cq/gui/components/authoring/dialog"
    helpPath="en/cq/current/wcm/default_components.html#Carousel">
    <content
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
        <layout
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/tabs"
            type="nav"/>
        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
            <generalSettings
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                jcr:title="General Settings"
                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/section">
                <layout
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/fixedcolumns"/>
                <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                    <column
                        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
                        <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                            <headingText
                                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield"
                                fieldLabel="Text"
                                name="./text"/>
                        </items>
                    </column>
                </items>
            </generalSettings>
            <componentSettings
                jcr:title="Component Settings"
                jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/include"
                path="mysite/dialogs/granite/tabs/componentSettings"/>
        </items>
    </content>
</jcr:root>
```

The reusable Component Settings tab lives at `/apps/mysite/dialogs/granite/tabs/componentSettings.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    jcr:title="Settings"
    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/section">
    <layout
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/layouts/fixedcolumns"
        margin="{Boolean}false"/>
    <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
        <column
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/container">
            <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
                <componentId
                    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
                    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield"
                    fieldLabel="Component Id"
                    name="./componentId"/>
            </items>
        </column>
    </items>
</jcr:root>
```